# Replacing values outside column-specific ranges of multiple columns in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I'm new to pandas and I want to clean a data frame with loads of columns.

I want to keep values that fall within a range specific for each column, eg for the column named 'Age' I want to keep values larger than 5 and smaller than 25. If a value falls outside of that range I want to replace it with NaN, eg in the 'Age' column there is the value 918 that I want to replace.

In my attempt I'm using a dictionary, because like I said I've got a lot of columns. This code doesn't work because it doesn't actually change any of the values in my original data frame (no error message).

Thanks for any help!

```
# PACKAGES 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 


# STARTING DATA 
data = [[1.0, 10, 0], [0.0, 12, 0.4], [2.0, 918, 0.9]]   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['TriGly', 'Age', 'Chol']) 

dict = {
    'Age': (5, 25),
    'Chol': (0.2, 1.2),
    'TriGly': (0.0, 1.0)
}


# CLEAN 
for column_name in df.columns:                                             
    if column_name in dict:                                                
        for row in df[column_name]:                                        
            if dict[column_name][0] < row < dict[column_name][1]:       
                row = row                                                   
            else:
                row = np.nan                                               

# DESIRED DATA 
data2 = [[1.0, 10, np.nan], [0.0, 12, 0.4], [np.nan, np.nan, 0.9]]   
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['TriGly', 'Age', 'Chol'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each column, you can use `.between(min_val, max_val)` to identify the valid values. Then you can use `.where` to mask the other values as `nan`. Finally, do a quick apply on the columns:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.where(x.between(*(my_dict[x.name])) ) )
```

Output:

```
   TriGly   Age  Chol
0     1.0  10.0   NaN
1     0.0  12.0   0.4
2     NaN   NaN   0.9
```